# Sending Child Control Item Value to Parent Form Textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, syntax, controls

I have been at this for quite some time today. Recently we completely converted our VB.NET project to C# and it works perfectly, in all aspects.

The problem we have however, is our **ListControlItem click listener** is wrong after conversion.

We have a FlowLayoutPanel named flpListBox and items are added in with Add() method within Form1_Load.

eg.

```
ListControl1.Add("name", "name2", "name3");
```

**Expected result**

When a user clicks the item in the ListControl (list), the Index or name is sent to lblNowPlaying.Text on parent form **Form1**.

VB.NET - Working

```
Private Sub ItemClicked(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
   RaiseEvent ItemClick(Me, flpListBox.Controls.IndexOfKey(sender.name))
End Sub
```

C# - **Not Working**

```
private void ItemClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ItemClick?.Invoke(this, flpListBox.Controls.IndexOfKey(ToString(sender.name)));
}
```

Now since code conversion it does not show any data on parent form and produces error below. The problem is **sender.name** it complains about "name".

This was working perfectly in VB.NET, I can't understand this bug for the life of me today.

I believe this is working fine as there are no syntax errors (again, working 100% in VB.NET). This is on Form1:

```
private void ListControl1_ItemClick(object sender, int Index)
{
   // Get the list item name clicked
   this.lblNowPlaying.Text = "Download: " + this.ListControl1.GetControl(Index).Song;
}
```

And VB.NET version

```
Private Sub ListControl1_ItemClick(sender As Object, Index As Integer) Handles ListControl1.ItemClick
   ' Get the list item name clicked
   lblNowPlaying.Text = "Download: " & ListControl1.GetControl(Index).Song
End Sub
```

Basically, this just changes the Form1 Text to whatever they clicked, in this case its the name.

I tried this to no effect

```
this.flpListBox.Controls.IndexOfKey(((Control)sender).Name);
flpListBox.Controls.IndexOfKey(DirectCast(sender, Control).Name)
```

Directcasting it etc.. I can't figure it out.

Please any help appreciated!

[image: Compiler Error CS1061]

Comment: *"it complains about `sender.name`"* - what exactly is the error? The cast is absolutely necessary, btw, since `sender` is an object, and certainly does not have a `.name`. Please add actual compiler error or exception.

Comment: Thank you, it is raising 'Compiler Error CS1061' - 'type' does not contain a definition for 'name' and no accessible extension method 'name' accepting a first argument of type 'type' could be found.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense - what is the actual control used (ListControl is a base for ComboBox and ListBox), and what *data type* are the items being stored? You can also comment out the problematic line, set a breakpoint instead (put a semicolon on an empty line in that event handler, and breakpoint it), and in the Immediate Window, see what is the `sender.GetType().Name`

Comment: By the way, the VB.NET version of this application was likely built without `Option Strict On`, or explicitly with `Option Strict Off` - is that correct?

Comment: I am 100% using this - https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/333864/Flexible-List-Control - It was a successful conversion however this one issue! I am not familiar with breakpoints, total switch from VB.NET so its a shock

Comment: Option Strict was never set in VB.NET project (forked from the sample download)

Comment: Your cast is to a wrong type - you're storing a custom type called `ListControlItem` if you're following that project you linked

Comment: Sorry please explain, in ListControl1_ItemClick -or- ItemClicked ? We are using that project entirely. Its all laid out however its now C# on our end.

Comment: Try `((Control)sender).Name`

Comment: I still have  problems with this 28 days later. This is the fix, but still wont send text over to parent form. I added all references in designer CS and double checked everything against the original source, I have no idea at this point but to keep researching

ListControlItem c = (ListControlItem)sender;
MessageBox.Show(c.Name);
ItemClick?.Invoke(this, flpListBox.Controls.IndexOfKey(c.Name));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your VB.NET code works is due to a language feature known as *late binding* - effectively allowing an implicit conversion (a rather expensive at-run-time one) of `Object` to `ListControlItem` type. This feature is only allowed in VB.NET code with `Option Strict Off` (default setting); however, C# does not have this feature at all.

So, the VB.NET code:

```vb
Private Sub ItemClicked(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
   RaiseEvent ItemClick(Me, flpListBox.Controls.IndexOfKey(sender.name)) 'expensive run-time cast and Late binding! 
End Sub
```

should really be (with `Option Strict On`):

```vb
Private Sub ItemClicked(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
   RaiseEvent ItemClick(Me, flpListBox.Controls.IndexOfKey((DirectCast(sender, ListControlItem).Name)) 'Compile-time checked, efficient cast!
End Sub
```

and in C#:

```cs
private void ItemClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ItemClick?.Invoke(this, flpListBox.Controls.IndexOfKey(ToString((sender as ListControlItem).Name)));
}
```

Also, a *very important difference* between the two languages is that *VB.NET is not case-sensitive*, while *C# is case-sensitive*! Note, that in the C# code (and the VB.NET `Option Strict On` code), I made the `name` property upper-case (which looks like it is in the VB.NET project you referenced) - but double-check your code. IntelliSense is your friend here - once you have it in the correct type, you'll see the properties listed in Visual Studio as you type.

More info on Option Strict and late binding: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement